# fprintf not writing to txt file

Tags: c, file

I have a program I am working on for my C assignment, and the section I am currently stuck on is deleting the last line of the file. In order to achieve this, I created a new file, and will later on delete the original file, and then rename the temporary file to the original file name.

However, I cannot even write anything to the temporary file.

```
void eraseFromFile(Song **tail) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *tempFp;
    char line[200];
    char lastEntry[200];
    int counter = 0;
    fp = fopen("playlist.txt", "r");
    tempFp = fopen("temp2.txt", "w+");

    if (fp == NULL || tempFp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file.");
        return;
    }

    // snprintf(lastEntry, sizeof(lastEntry), "%s*%s*%s*%d",
    //          (*tail)->artist, (*tail)-> album,
    //          (*tail)->title,(*tail)->year);
    // printf("this is the last entry:\n%s\n",lastEntry);

    while (fgets(line, 200, fp) != NULL) {
    
        if (counter == fileLength - 1) {
            return;
        }
  
        printf("%d", fileLength);
        fprintf(tempFp, "%s", line);

        counter++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(tempFp);
}
```

here is the original text file:

```
BLACKPINK*Born Pink*Pink Venom*2022
Adele*21*Rolling in the Deep*2011
TWICE*Between 1&2*Queen of Hearts*2022
Backstreet Boys*Backstreet’s Back*As Long As You Love Me*1997
Taylor Swift*Midnights*Lavender Haze*2022
Lee Hi*4 Only*ONLY*2021
Westlife*Coast to Coast*My Love*2000
Ed Sheeran*Divide*Perfect*2017
IU*LILAC*Celebrity*2021
```

and here is how its called in `main()`:

```
void eraseLastData(Song **tail) {
    Song *lastData;

    if ((*tail) == NULL) {
        printf("the playlist is currently empty...");
        return;
    }
  
    lastData = (*tail);

    (*tail) = lastData->prevSong;
    (*tail)->nextSong = NULL;
    lastData->prevSong = NULL;
    free(lastData);
}

int main() {
    int selection;

    while (true) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (inMenu) {
            displayMenu();
            do {
                if (counter > 0)
                    printf("selection out of range, please select a valid option");

                scanSelection(&selection);
                counter++;
            } while(selection > 4 || selection < 1);

            inMenu = false;
        }

        system("cls");

        switch (selection) {

          case 3:
            eraseLastData(&tail);
            eraseFromFile(&tail);
            promptMenu(&inMenu);
            break;

          case 4:
            clearList(&head);
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At first I thought it was an issue with the linked list I coded, but a quick `printf` in the `eraseFromFile` `while` loop (which I excluded from the code) showed that there was nothing wrong with the linked list itself, and it was just that `fprintf` wasn't working. The temporary text file is currently empty. I have tried everything from manual debugging to asking chatgpt, but even it couldn't find any weird errors with my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure `fprintf()` is very well debugged. Perhaps something is wrong with your code? Kindly edit the question to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Now what exactly is `fileLength`, and how was the function called?

Comment: Show a [mcve]. The problem might be in the code you didn't show.

Comment: oh wait my bad, i forgot to edit it out @Haris. Its not really relevant to the example

Comment: What happens if you print `line` to terminal before printing to file?

Comment: @Gerhardh it prints each line of the original txt file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i have updated the code to show how its being called and the accompanying functions

Comment: `eraseFromFile` works fine. I'm not sure what temp2.txt is supposed to contain after `eraseFromFile` has been called, but it definitely contains lines from playlist.txt and lines containing "Hello"

Comment: `fprintf(tempFp, "%s\n", line)` prints 2 line-feeds.  One from the string, one from the format.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry, youre right. Turns out it was printing as expected. However, when I add the logic to exclude the last line from printing into the temp file , it no longer prints into the file. I have edited the post to account for this error.

Comment: Do you overwrite that temp file afterwards in one of the other functions you don't show us?

Comment: @Gerhardh nope, that was the only function in my C code that had access to the temp file.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry, I dont quite get what you mean. Isnt it only supposed to print the format?

Comment: What is `filelength`? Provide a [mcve] <<--- **read this**

Comment: @k12293139 `fprintf()` does not just print the format. The `"%s"` directs the function to print the string, pointed to by `line`, which likely has a `'\n'` and then print `"\n"`, which is another `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the value of 'counter' and 'filelength' in the eraseFromFile function, especially the following section;

```
if (counter == fileLength - 1) {
 return;
}
```

I have also noticed that 'counter' is incremented by one while I assume that 'fileLength' is the number of bytes in the file and you are reading 200 bytes from the file. Therefore, the two variables are not synchronized properly. That is one counts the number of 200 bytes read (counter) and the other stores the number of bytes in the file (fileLength).

Try changing;

```
counter++;
```

To;

```
counter = (counter + 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy all but the last line from the input file to the output file, you need to delay writing the previous line until you successfully read the next line.

It is recommended to check for errors and output meaningful error messages.  This helps understand the program behavior and detect programming errors.

Here is a modified version of `eraseFromFile` taking the file names as arguments for reusability, with error checking and detailed error messages.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// return the number of lines copied, -1 on error
int eraseFromFile(const char *inputname, const char *outputname) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(inputname, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open file %s: %s\n",
                inputname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *tempFp = fopen(outputname, "w");  // no need for w+
    if (tempFp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open file %s: %s\n",
                outputname, strerror(errno));
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    char line[200];
    char lastEntry[200];
    int counter = 0;

    if (fgets(lastEntry, sizeof lastEntry, fp)) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
            if (fputs(lastEntry, tempFp) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not write to file %s: %s",
                        outputname, strerror(errno));
                fclose(tempFp);
                fclose(fp);
                return -1;
            }
            counter++;
            strcpy(lastEntry, line);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(tempFp);
    return counter;
}
```

Use this function as:

```
    int count = eraseFileFile("playlist.txt", "temp2.txt");
    if (count >= 0) {
        if (remove("playlist.txt")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot remove %s: %s\n",
                    "playlist.txt", strerror(errno));
        } else
        if (rename("temp2.txt", "playlist.txt")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot rename %s as %s: %s\n",
                    "temp2.txt", "playlist.txt", strerror(errno));
        }
    } else {
        remove("temp2.txt");
    }
```